# How to insert record in many to many join table without doing a join first?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, relationship

I have two entities (User and Book) with many to many relationship between them

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String title;

    private int version;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "books")
    private List<User> users;

    public Author getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(Author author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    long id;
    
    String name;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "checkout", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    List<Book> books;


    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }


    public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }
}
```

A user can checkout many books and a book can be checked out by many users. Say, I have an API end point
 `checkout(User user,Book book)`

I need to checkout a book for a user, basically I need to make a entry in the join table checkout. The only way I can think of doing things, is by doing something like this

```
user.getBooks().add(book)
session.save(user);
```

Using this approach will involve a join between user and checkout tables.

Is there any way to do this without the join?

Answer (score 0):

With plain JPA or Hibernate the answer is no. You can either use SQL directly or you use Blaze-Persistence which has support for collection DML on top of the JPA model: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/core/manual/en_US/#insert-select-collection-statement